# minikube on windows: storageclass.storage.k8s.io not found

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I am trying to deploy a service on minikube(with hyper-V on windows 11) using yaml file.

On dashboard, I see that corresponding pod remains in 'pending' state for ever.

When I check the events, I see:

> storageclass.storage.k8s.io "local-path" not found

Looking into yaml, I see this entry:

> storageClassName: "local-path"

So error clearly states something is wrong with storageClassName.

What is appropriate value for storageClassName to workaround it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have specific reason to know a specific storage class should be used (your cluster administrator has created a storage class for some specific purpose and told you to use it), you should omit the `storageClassName:` line entirely.  This will use the cluster default; in Minikube that's the [default storage provisioner](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/persistent_volumes/#dynamic-provisioning-and-csi).